# Отправить на сервер данные в формате JSON

Tags: java, json, android-studio, post

Как отправить на сервер данные JSON методом POST используя авторизации в заголовке Authorization

Пример JSON данных отправляемые на сервер:

Header:  Authorization  Bearer UXFTltj-kISwxisaawt2elpDbkvy

```
{
"status": "active",
"error": "No error",
"type": "sms",
"data": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Кукуруза на Марсе",
    "params": {
        "1": "Возможно",
        "2": "Невозможно",
        "3": "Бред",
        "4": "А где это?",
        "6": "А что это?"
    }
}}
```

Comment: Может [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp#okhttp) подойдёт

Comment: Я только начал изучать, если вам не сложно можно описать решение более подробнее, а еще лучше дать исходный код, для изучения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Вот копия примера [отсюда](http://square.github.io/okhttp/#examples), с добавлением одной строчки, отвечающей за заголовок авторизации. В этом примере мы определяем функцию `post`, которая принимает две строки — `url` (адрес куда отправляем запрос) и `json` (строка с json-объектом).

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)

// эта строчка была добавлена
      .header("Authorization", "Bearer UXFTltj-kISwxisaawt2elpDbkvy")
// ============

      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!